# Hover Over String and Update Preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#3d4399e2bde4c474186bd1c730539334

I'm working with two strings here (an image and a color)

```
<div class="stuff">
  #0af
  http://cdn1.theodysseyonline.com/files/2015/11/14/6358312506953272101532239493_l-Baby-bear.jpg
</div>
```

[*Color values and images change depending on user input.*](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#3d4399e2bde4c474186bd1c730539334)

This question is just about displaying the image. As [I already got color values working](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#3d4399e2bde4c474186bd1c730539334).

I'm using the following RegEx to check if the string has an image...

```
var image = /(http(s?):)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/g;
```

What I'd like to figure out is..

- If I hover over a url linking to an image how can I show that image in `.preview` (as an image tag) using [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```js
// Handles Preview Position
$(document).on('ready mousemove', function(e) {
  if (e.pageX >= $(window).width() - 100) { 
    if (e.pageY <= $(window).height() - 100) { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY,
        'left' : e.pageX - 134
      })
    } else { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 100,
        'left' : e.pageX - 134
      })
    }
  } else if (e.pageX >= 60) { 
    if (e.pageY <= $(window).height() - 100) { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY,
        'left' : e.pageX - 64
      })
    } else { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 100,
        'left' : e.pageX - 64
      })
    }
  } else if (e.pageX <= 60) { 
    if (e.pageY <= $(window).height() - 100) { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY,
        'left' : e.pageX
      })
    } else { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 100,
        'left' : e.pageX
      })
    }
  }
})
// Add Preview
$('body').append('<div class="preview"></div>');

// Initialize CodeMirror editor
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  mode: "text/css",
  tabMode: "indent",
  styleActiveLine: true,
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  autoCloseTags: true,
  foldGutter: true,
  dragDrop: true,
  lint: true,
  gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers", "CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"]
})

$('.CodeMirror-line').on('mouseover', function() {
  var hsl = /hsla?\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}\%)\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}\%)\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\)/g;
  var rgb = /rgba?\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\)/g;
  var hex = /#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}/g;
  var colors = /hsla?\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}\%)\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}\%)\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\)|rgba?\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\)|#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}/g;
  var image = /(http(s?):)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/g;
  if (!this.textContent.match(colors) == "") {
   $('.preview').css('visibility', 'visible');
   $('.preview').empty().html( $('<div/>').addClass('color').css('background', this.textContent.match(colors)) )
  } else if (!this.textContent.match(image) == "") {
   $('.preview').css('visibility', 'visible');
   $('.preview').empty().html('<img src="'+ this.textContent.match(image) + '">')
  } else {
    $('.preview').empty().css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
})
```

```css
.CodeMirror {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.preview {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.color {
  width: 80px;
}
.preview img, .color {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.0.0/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldgutter.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/css/css.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/closetag.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/selection/active-line.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldcode.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldgutter.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/brace-fold.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/xml-fold.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/comment-fold.js"></script>

<textarea id="code">.CodeMirror {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #2e8f2e;
  background: url('http://cdn1.theodysseyonline.com/files/2015/11/14/6358312506953272101532239493_l-Baby-bear.jpg');
}

iframe {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  color: hsl(232,100%,46%);
  border: 1px solid rgb(191, 92, 209);
  border-left: 0;
}</textarea>
```

Comment: I'm thinking you're going to want to use regular expression to validate color codes and image links and have it work something like: search div.stuff, if color found wrap with `<span class="color"></span>` if image link found wrap with `<span class="img"></span>` then all you'd have to do is target those span tags.

Comment: "Color values and images change depending on user input." ... so what code is causing these changes and can it be used somehow? (event or var)

Comment: "Color values and images change depending on user input." is because I'm working with [Codemirror](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#b010fdda3961f2841274656a6e402beb)

Comment: Are both, the color and the image link, inside the same div? If you have the option that they are inside separate span-tags `<span>color</span><span>image-link</span>` you could attach an event handler and read the inside value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#f5643481378a470cd08ea0d848319883

I assume there's a cleaner and more accurate way to do this, but here's my grotesque solution.

I use `var image` to check if the string is a valid image.
I then use `var addimage` to add the string url.

```
var image = /(http(s?):)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/g;
var addimage = /(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}(\.[a-z]{2,6}|:[0-9]{3,4})\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/g;
```

Then by using the [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) event. I look for the string and if it matches the variable I display it, if it I don't.

```
$('.CodeMirror-line').on('mouseover', function() {
  var image = /(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}(\.[a-z]{2,6}|:[0-9]{3,4})\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/g;
  if (!this.textContent.match(image) == "") {
    $('.preview').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.preview').empty().html('<img src="'+ this.textContent.match(image) +'">')
  } else {
    $('.preview').empty().css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
})
```

```js
// Handles Preview Position
$(document).on('ready mousemove', function(e) {
  if (e.pageX >= $(window).width() - 100) { 
    if (e.pageY <= $(window).height() - 100) { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY,
        'left' : e.pageX - 134
      })
    } else { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 100,
        'left' : e.pageX - 134
      })
    }
  } else if (e.pageX >= 60) { 
    if (e.pageY <= $(window).height() - 100) { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY,
        'left' : e.pageX - 64
      })
    } else { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 100,
        'left' : e.pageX - 64
      })
    }
  } else if (e.pageX <= 60) { 
    if (e.pageY <= $(window).height() - 100) { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY,
        'left' : e.pageX
      })
    } else { 
      $('.preview').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 100,
        'left' : e.pageX
      })
    }
  }
})
// Add Preview
$('body').append('<div class="preview"></div>');

// Initialize CodeMirror editor
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  mode: "text/css",
  tabMode: "indent",
  styleActiveLine: true,
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  autoCloseTags: true,
  foldGutter: true,
  dragDrop: true,
  lint: true,
  gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers", "CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"]
})

$('.CodeMirror-line').on('mouseover', function() {
  var hsl = /hsla?\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}\%)\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}\%)\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\)/g;
  var rgb = /rgba?\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\)/g;
  var hex = /#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}/g;
  var colors = /hsla?\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}\%)\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}\%)\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\)|rgba?\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\)|#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}/g;
  var image = /(http(s?):)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/g;
  var addimage = /(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}(\.[a-z]{2,6}|:[0-9]{3,4})\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/g;
  if (!this.textContent.match(colors) == "") {
   $('.preview').css('visibility', 'visible');
   $('.preview').empty().html( $('<div/>').addClass('color').css('background', this.textContent.match(colors)) )
  } else if (!this.textContent.match(image) == "") {
   $('.preview').css('visibility', 'visible');
   $('.preview').empty().html('<img src="'+ this.textContent.match(addimage) +'">')
  } else {
    $('.preview').empty().css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
})
```

```css
.CodeMirror {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.preview {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.color {
  width: 80px;
}
.preview img, .color {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.0.0/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldgutter.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/css/css.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/closetag.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/selection/active-line.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldcode.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldgutter.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/brace-fold.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/xml-fold.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/comment-fold.js"></script>

<textarea id="code">.CodeMirror {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #2e8f2e;
  background: url('http://cdn1.theodysseyonline.com/files/2015/11/14/6358312506953272101532239493_l-Baby-bear.jpg');
}

iframe {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  color: hsl(232,100%,46%);
  border: 1px solid rgb(191, 92, 209);
  border-left: 0;
}</textarea>
```